# Rails4 scope with parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I somehow cannot find any place in the rails documentation about how to put some params into a named scope, f.e. something like this

scope :by_id, -> { where :id = id }

Comment: possible duplicate of [scopes with lambda and arguments in Rails 4 style?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588077/scopes-with-lambda-and-arguments-in-rails-4-style)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
scope :by_id, ->(id) {where (:id => id)}
```

this should work

Comment: Why does adding a space between `->` and `(id)` break?