# Rails 4: scope only if user is not signed in

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to use something like

```
scope :published, -> { where(:published => true) }
```

on my Article model *only if the user is not signed in*. If the user is signed in then I'd like to show all articles. I realize that the Article model itself does not have access to Devise's `user_signed_in?` method so this logic should probably live in the controller.

The problem is that in the controller it would cause a lot of redundancy, as such:

```
def index
  if params[:search].present?
    @search = params[:search]
    if user_signed_in?
      @articles = Article.where('title LIKE ? OR body LIKE ?', "%#{@search}%", "%#{@search}%")
    else
      @articles = Article.published.where('title LIKE ? OR body LIKE ?', "%#{@search}%", "%#{@search}%")
    end
  elsif params[:uid].present?
    @user = User.find(params[:uid])
    if user_signed_in?
      @articles = @user.articles.order :created_at
    else
      @articles = @user.articles.published.order :created_at
    end
  else
    if user_signed_in?
      @articles = Article.all.desc
    else
      @articles = Article.published.desc
    end
  end
end
```

Is there a better way I can avoid redundancy here but always check if the user is signed in before using the `published` scope?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into using pundit, you can scope access exactly in this way for access control.

You can pass current_user to you scope.

```
scope :search, -> (current_user) { where(published: [(current_user.present? ? false : true), true]) }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16588246/1162683

Comment: Thanks, Pundit might be exactly what I need to keep this simple.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, extract the second `where` clause into a scope of its own. This will make things easier to re-use.

Secondly, ActiveRecord queries are composable and lazy. This means that you can save off an intermediate query into a variable, then attach the scope.

```
class Article
  scope :search, -> {|search| where('title LIKE ? OR body LIKE ?', "%#{@search}%", "%#{@search}%") }
....
end

class ArticlesController
  def index
    articles = Article.search(params[:search])
    articles.published if user_signed_in?
  end
end
```

Something like that

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear. My question is: how can I do something like this `scope :published, -> { user_signed_in? ? all : where(:published => true) }`
This isn't possible within the model so I was wondering if there's a better way to do that in the controller

Comment: it is not a best practice to call user_signed_in? method in the model, because it is a controller business
so I think the refactored code suggested by @Srdjan is pretty enough

Comment: The thing is that action is already doing too much, even without having the `user_signed_in?` problem. Why not split out into 3 separate actions, `index` which runs the code in the `else` clause, `search`, which does the search code and then whatever `uid` does.